# html MediaRecorder save last n seconds

Tags: html5-video, media-source

I'm using MediaRecorder and receive video by chunks in dataavailable. I would like to do 2 things with these chunks:

1. Save only the last n sec of a video. I noticed that just concatenating all the chunks in a video file generates a valid video file. Though, as soon as I start to remove some chunks from the beginning (let's say taking only the last 10 chunks to save only the last 10s of the video) then the resulting file is not valid anymore. I expect this is due to missing metadata or something.
2. I'm trying to send these chunks using socket io and read them from another browser using MediaSource. It kind of worked as long as I read the chunks from the beginning again. If I start reading after the server started to send the chunks, I receive chunks but not from the beginning and it fails to display the video.

Are there ways to avoid these problems?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem? Because I am dealing with the same thing and unsure what to do.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck on my side. I suspect it would be some headers info that are only in the first part that are missing if you cut it.

Comment: From what I understand, there are "starter" segments necessary for the video playing algorithm -- at least for most common container formats like MPEG-4. If you omit chunks in the beginning, these segments are unavailable and your assembled (out of chunks) container is invalid or at least hard to recover playability for. The only way I have understood to avoid the problem is to provide the segments. Of course, this begs asking -- where, as in how many bytes or chunks, are these segments? Perhaps worth reading [the relevant specification](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/)...